# CMake doesn't add dependency libraries to the project files

Tags: visual-studio, boost, cmake

I am writing a simple example code using pcl just as the link 
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_pcd.php.

Even though I follow the link, Visual studio reports link errors.
The reason is that pcl depends on boost library and cmake doesn't
add boost library to the project setting files of visual studio.
If I add boost library with the following line, everything will be OK.

target_link_libraries(progname ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

Why doesn't CMake handle this? Is there a better solution?

CMake: 3.13.2,

Visual studio: Community 2017

PCL: PCL-1.9.1-AllInOne-msvc2017-win64.exe

**Edit:** 
CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MY_GRAND_PROJECT)
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
find_package(Boost 1.45.0) 

find_package(PCL 1.9.1 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable(pcd_write_test pcd_write.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pcd_write_test ${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES}  ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Strange. In their repo, at the end of [PCLConfig.cmake](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/pcl-1.9.1/PCLConfig.cmake.in) they add `${BOOST_LIBRARIES}` (which is previously assigned to `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`) to the `PCL_LIBRARIES` variable. You may check that file in your PCL installation.

Comment: BTW, on Stack Overflow we tend to have the code **in the question post** itself. Even if you exactly follows an existing documentation, it is better to copy-paste the code into the question post. So the question will become valid even if documentation has been changed or disappear. (And you may have some small corrections in the code, about which we don't know). Of course, only `CMakeLists.txt` is sufficient to show the problem, `.cpp` code is unrelated.

Comment: Thanks. From your comment, I learn that third party libraries are appended to PCL_LIBRARIES. In CMakeLists.txt, I only use two components from the pcl library.  @Tsyvarev You can write one answer.I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PCLConfig.cmake](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/pcl-1.9.1/PCLConfig.cmake.in) script in the official repo, Boost libraries are appended to the `PCL_LIBRARIES` variable. (This is performed near the end of the script).

So, for automatically link with Boost libraries when use PCL, you need to use `PCL_LIBRARIES` variable for linking, not `PCL_<comp>_LIBRARIES` variables.

---

I don't know, whether given behaviour is intended or not. If you assume that Boost libraries should be part of `PCL_<comp>_LIBRARIES` variables too, then you may fill a bug-report about that.